# Play 2.0 access play's default Akka actor system from FakeApplication in Java

Tags: playframework-2.0, akka

I am writing a test case to test akka actor. However, I have to create a separate Akka system outside of fake application. Is there a way to get akka actor system from FakeApplication?

```
public class ChannelWorkerTest {

    private TestActorRef<ChannelWorker> actorRef;
    private ActorSystem actorSystem;

    @Before
    public void initActor() {
        actorSystem = ActorSystem.apply();
        actorRef = TestActorRef.apply(new Props(ChannelWorker.class), actorSystem);
    }


    @Test
    public void calculatePiFor1() {
        running(fakeApplication(TestConf.getConf()), new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
              TestProbe testProbe = TestProbe.apply(actorSystem);
              .....
              actorRef.tell(aMessage, testProbe.ref());
              }
        });
    }

    @After
    public void shutdownActorSystem() {
        actorSystem.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did.

```
public class MyHelpers extends Helpers {

    /**
     * Build a new fake application.
     */
    public static MyFakeApplication myFakeApplication(Map<String,String> additionalConfiguration,
        List<String> withoutPlugins, List<String> additionalPlugin) {
        return new MyFakeApplication(new java.io.File("."), MyHelpers.class.getClassLoader(),
            additionalConfiguration, withoutPlugins, additionalPlugin);
    }

    /**
     * Executes a block of code in a running application.
     */
    public static void myRunning(MyFakeApplication fakeApplication, final Runnable block) {
    try {
        myStart(fakeApplication);
        block.run();
    } finally {
        myStop(fakeApplication);
            play.core.Invoker$.MODULE$.system().shutdown();
            play.core.Invoker$.MODULE$.uninit();
    }
    }
}


public class ChannelWorkerTest {
    private MyFakeApplication app;
    private TestActorRef<ChannelWorker> actorRef;
    private ActorSystem actorSystem;

    @Before
    public void initTest() {
    app = myFakeApplication(TestConf.getConf(), withoutPlugins, additionalPlugins);
        actorSystem = play.api.libs.concurrent.Akka.system(app.getWrappedApplication());
        actorRef = TestActorRef.apply(new Props(new UntypedActorFactory() {
            public UntypedActor create() {
                return new MessageMaster(Config.NUMBER_OF_WORKER_ACTOR);
            }
        }), actorSystem);
    }


    @Test
    public void calculatePiFor1() {
        running(fakeApplication(TestConf.getConf()), new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                 TestProbe testProbe = TestProbe.apply(actorSystem);
                 actorRef.tell("Hello", testProbe.ref());
                 testProbe.expectNoMsg(Duration.apply(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
              }
        });
    }

    @After
    public void shutdownActorSystem() {
        actorSystem.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to get the Akka actor system using the static method `Akka.system()`.

But I don't think it works with a FakeApplication, you may need to start your Play server using the [testServer() helper](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/JavaFunctionalTest):

```
@Test
public void testInServer() {
  running(testServer(3333), new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
         ActorSystem  actorSystem = Akka.system();
         // do whatever you need
      }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just did this in a scala test. But you have to init the actor inside of the running block. I am guessing it would work the same in java - but I haven't tested it in java. I didn't need to actually start a web server.